# How can I destroy a session if user goes back to the previous page in ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to make a Admin Login page and I want system to destroy the admin_email_session if user goes back to the previous page.

I asked ChatGPT for it and it gave me this solution but it did not work.How can I solve the problem ?

```
    app.get("/Admin-Panel",function(req,res){

        console.log(req.session.admin_email_session);

        if(req.session.admin_email_session===undefined){

            console.log("asd");
        }

        else{

            fs.readFile("Admin-Panel/admin-panel.html","utf-8",function(err,data){

                if(err){
                    throw err;
                }
                else{

                    res.write(data);
                    res.end();
                }
            });

             //True and False are parameters

            app.get("/Admin-Panel-true",function(req,res){

                req.session.destroy;
            });

            app.get("/Admin-Panel-false",function(req,res){

                req.session.destroy;
            });
        }
        
    });
```

Comment: Clicking a back button is just another request to your api. I don't think your api will be able to detect it

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```js
`// Check if 'admin_email_session' exists in the session, if not, destroy the session
if (!req.session.admin_email_session) {
  req.session.destroy();
}

// Send the 'admin-panel.html' file to the client
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('Admin-Panel/admin-panel.html', 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  res.end(data);
});`
```